# Issue sending AJAX request to another domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use this API: https://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/API

But when I make the AJAX call, I'm getting this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/rest//radius.json/30341/10/mile.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Here is the request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/rest/<api key goes here...>/radius.json/30341/10/mile',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(zipback) {
    }
});
```

I know it has something to do with making the request from a different domain, but I don't not how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you do the steps @ https://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/ClientKeySetup ? What did that result in?

Comment: Cross domain requests should probably be `dataType: jsonp`

Comment: @NG. that worked...brain fart...thanks!

Comment: In order to get a JSON file from another domain, as @TheMuffinMan said, you need to label it as `dataType: "jsonp",` or the browser won't let you get it b/c of security reasons.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan: Nope, they don't seem to support JSONP. However, CORS would work as in the [examples](https://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/Examples).

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/rest/<api key goes here...>/radius.json/30341/10/mile',
    dataType: "json",
    jsonpCallback:'somename',
    success: function(zipback) {
    }
});
```